# eslint imports in webpack: Unable to resolve path to module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

With eslint-import-resolver-webpack I'm trying to let eslint know that I want to import files, by referencing a "shortcut" (eg. components/Counter).

In the example below, webpack (v2.2.0-rc.3) builds fine, but the test fails because it's "Unable to resolve path to module 'components/Counter'".
I get this error also for importing 'components/Counter/reducer', so it's not limited to index.

Both running `npm run lint` and my IDE (IntelliJ) give the same error.

Following the docs, I've set the following configs:

(Part of) file structure:

```
project-root/
  app/
    components/
      Counter/
        index.js
        reducer.js
    app.js
 internals/ 
   config/
      .eslintrc
      webpack.test.js
  package.json
```

File: project-root/app/app.js

```js
import Counter from 'components/Counter'
// etc...
```

Excerpt of: project-root/package.json

```
...
"lint": "npm run lint:eslint -- . ",
"lint:eslint": "eslint -c internals/config/.eslintrc --fix --ignore-path .gitignore --ignore-pattern internals"
...
```

File: project-root/config/.eslintrc

```json
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "mocha": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "redux-saga",
    "react",
    "jsx-a11y"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "webpack": {
        "config": "./internals/config/webpack.test.js"
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "arrow-parens": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ],
    "import/imports-first": 0,
    "import/newline-after-import": 0,
    "import/no-dynamic-require": 0,
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": 0,
    "import/no-named-as-default": 0,
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/aria-props": 2,
    "jsx-a11y/heading-has-content": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": 2,
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": 2,
    "jsx-a11y/mouse-events-have-key-events": 2,
    "jsx-a11y/role-has-required-aria-props": 2,
    "jsx-a11y/role-supports-aria-props": 2,
    "max-len": [
      2,
      120,
      2,
      {
        "ignoreComments": true,
        "ignoreTrailingComments": false,
        "ignoreRegExpLiterals": true
      }
    ],
    "newline-per-chained-call": [
      2,
      {
        "ignoreChainWithDepth": 4
      }
    ],
    "no-console": [
      1,
      {
        "allow": [
          "warn",
          "error"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "no-use-before-define": [
      2,
      {
        "functions": false,
        "classes": true
      }
    ],
    "prefer-template": 2,
    "class-methods-use-this": 0,
    "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 2,
    "react/jsx-first-prop-new-line": [
      2,
      "multiline"
    ],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
    "react/jsx-no-target-blank": 0,
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": 0,
    "react/require-extension": 0,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 0,
    "redux-saga/no-yield-in-race": 2,
    "redux-saga/yield-effects": 2,
    "semi": [
      2,
      "never"
    ]
  }
}
```

And: project-root/internals/config/webpack.test.js:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },

      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'null-loader' },

      { test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
      },

      { test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$/i,
        loader: 'null-loader',
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      },
    }),
  ],

  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'app',
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },
}
```

Note: I've also tried pointing to a file that only exports the resolve object. Same thing:

```js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      'app',
      'node_modules',
    ],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed my dependencies needed updating...

There's quite a lot of plugins, configs, etc needed for a thorough linting process..

**-- edit --**

Here's an excerpt of my projects' dependencies. There might be some packages in here that are not necessary, I removed only the ones of which I'm sure that don't have an impact.

Note that front-end land moves like a cheetah in 6th gear, so the versions might get outdated soon. Anyway, as of now (feb 2017) this is a working configuration.

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "6.16.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "6.21.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "2.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "6.17.0",
    "babel-register": "6.22.0",
    "eslint": "3.13.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "14.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "3.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "0.1.5",
    "webpack": "2.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.9.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.14.0"
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as you, but all my dependencies are up to date. Any ideas?

Comment: @Zephir77167 first make sure you don't have any warnings/errors. Sometimes some peerDependencies are out of date. You'll be notified of that via a warning. If all is fine, try removing your `node_modules` folder and re-installing the whole thing with `npm install`.
If that doesn't fix it, depending on your stack, it might be required that you use a very new version of a package, an RC or even beta package. Check the github releases tab to see if there's something newer available. And then, again update dependencies accordingly

Comment: Hi, I found the source of my problem... I had to use path.resolve in .eslintrc > settings > import/resolver > webpack > config !

Comment: For someone, wondering here like me, searching for answer: 
Solution from here helped me to get it working https://stackoverflow.com/a/45003022/4603159

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have missed some config in `.eslintrc,js`:

```js
    'import/resolver': {
...,
      webpack: {
        config: {
          resolve: {
            alias: {
              // map your aliases here eg:
              components: '/src/components',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
```