# Eslint errorring importing jsx without extension

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am trying, in es6, to import jsx files without requiring the .jsx extension:

```
import LoginErrorDialog from './LoginErrorDialogView';
```

Not:

```
import LoginErrorDialog from './LoginErrorDialogView.jsx';
```

While I have got webpack to import in this fashion successfully:

```
export default {
  entry: './src/ui/js/app.js',
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
```

Eslint (`esw webpack.config.* ./ --color --ext .js --ext .jsx`) is still errorring.

`Unable to resolve path to module './LoginView'  import/no-unresolved`

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that's not a webpack error, that's eslint telling you that the path to `LoginView` cannot be found. See https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unresolved.md

Comment: @redconservatory I agree, the problem I'm finding is that I cannot have eslint recognize jsx files, and as a result am having to ignore the line.  I have JSX set to true in my eslint file, but it still does recognize the files.

Comment: So if you have eslint installed globally, you have to also install `eslint-plugin-react` globally for `jsx:true` to work (WTF!?). If it's a personal project I would recommend installing JS Standard instead. If it's a work project I would not use global node modules and install `eslint` and `eslint-plugin-react` locally to your project only...if you're using an editor like `Sublime` or `Atom` you might need to dive into the local lint settings...

Comment: @redconservatory unfortunately its a work project. Either way, I had eslint installed locally and installing globally didn't appear to resolve the problem anyhow.  Its a doozy!

Answer (score 30):

I had the same issue here, and I fixed adding extra configuration in my `.eslintrc`.

In the `extends` property add:

```
"plugin:import/react"
```

In the `settings` property add:

```
"import/resolver": {
  "node": {
    "extensions": [".js",".jsx"]
   }
}
```

Your `.eslintrc` will look like:

```
{
    "extends": [
        ...
        "plugin:import/react",
        ...
    ],
   ...
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
          "node": {
            "extensions": [".js",".jsx"]
          }
        }
    },
...
}
```

Comment: I have issues with importing in files at root. How can that be resolved?

Comment: I didn’t get your question!

Comment: This solution works for files within src. However eslint could not resolve path for files at root. How can that be resolved?

Comment: That no make any sense to me, it seems more related to your configuration, like webpack than eslint.

Comment: Worked for me thank you! just bear in mind after the changes you need to do `npm start` basically a restart.

Comment: Ohh , you are a lifesaver! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Add to rule section, below `rule`

`"import/extensions": [0, { "js": "always" }]`