# Module not found: Can't resolve '/root/project/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js in react app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, eslint

I am trying to build my first project with React, using the material-ui-kit from Creative Tim, but I get an error while trying to import a component. My file structure is as follows:

```
project
|
+--src
   |
   +--components
   |  |
   |  +--CustomButtons
   |     |
   |     +--Button.js
   +--Views
      |
      +--AdminView
         |
         +--Sections
         |  |
         |  +--Section1.js     
         |  +--Section2.js
         +--AdminView.js
```

From within Section1.js I import Button like so:

```
import Button from "components/CustomButtons/Button.js";
```

and this works fine. But when I do the same from section2.js, I get the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/views/AdminView/Sections/MaterialTable.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '/root/project/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js' in '/root/project'
```

I have tried everything I can think of, and spent hours looking this up, but I can't figure it out. Both files are in the same directory, the import works in one but not the other. I have made the code in both files exactly the same to try but it's not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

The jsconfig.json file in the project has the following content:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

if I am not mistaken, this is why `"components/CustomButtons/Button.js"` will work, and `"../../components/CustomButtons/Button.js"` is not needed.

Comment: I run **npm update** and it finally worked. I read this quiestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601942/eslint-imports-in-webpack-unable-to-resolve-path-to-module?rq=1, that suggested to update dependencies. It was a silly problem, but I'll leave the question and add an answer in case someone else has a similar issue.

Comment: Question: does your import in Selection1.js `import Button from "components/CustomButtons/Button.js";` - works? By looking into your project structure it looks like the correct path is `import Button from "../../components/CustomButtons/Button.js";`

Comment: It works... I think because of the jsconfig.json file, I'll add it to the question. By the way I also tried `"../../components/CustomButtons/Button.js";` before I updated dependencies.

Comment: Aha, they have probably used [resolve.alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) in webpack config :)

Comment: I got the same problem. After having updated some npm dependencies (from `npm audit`) I got this silly error. Turns out I had incompatible versions of different packages after updating. Reverting to my old `package.json` has solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why this happened, but I resolved the issue by running **npm update** on the project.

It may be worth noting that this happened after I installed a lot of npm dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing eslint-loader with the following command. This worked for me

`npm install eslint-loader --save-dev`